# Calling Ajax after every 4 digit input

Tags: jquery, ajax

User input is something like 'XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX', now I want to make an Ajax call to get Data from Db every-time when user type 4 digits, then next Ajax call when User type more 4 digits and so on to get more precise results.

```
$('#myInput').on('change', function(){

  // Don't exactly know what to do here //

  var myData = $(this).val();

  if(myData > 4){
    $.ajax({
      type : 'get',
      url  : 'myUrl.php?data='+myData,
      success : function(data){
        $('myDataDiv').html(data);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: To be more precise first Ajax call should be made on 4 digit input, second ajax call on 8 digit input and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `if(myData.length && myData.length % 4 == 0)` this will get the length of your string and compare the modulo 4 to 0.
If you want to allow blank spaces between the 4 digit groups you need to deal with those as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should use class for all those 4 inputs and then change the jquery selector with class like given below.

```
$('.myInput').on('change', function(){ // consider `myInput` is class...

  var myData = $(this).val();

  if(myData.length % 4 == 0){
    $.ajax({
      type : 'get',
      url  : 'myUrl.php?data='+myData,
      success : function(data){
        $('myDataDiv').html(data);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

because if you will use id like `#myInput` then jquery will consider only 1st id from top of DOM and your code may not work as expected.

Comment: there is just ONE input NOT four input

Comment: ok then you can keep the jquery selector as it is but then change `if` condition to check length to consider every 4 elements. I have updated my answer with proper `if` condition.

Answer (score 0):

`var myData = $(this).val();` This line will give you value inside text box. to get the number of characters in the input you have to use `.length`.

```
var myData = $(this).val();
if((myData.length % 4) === 0){

}
```

Comment: _"...after every 4 digit input"_

Comment: But, can this make another Ajax call when user type next 4 digits? To be more first Ajax call on 4 digit input, second ajax request on 8 digit input and so on.